# Writing a database connection in index.php file

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a PDO connection to  database in `index.php` file.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbname";
$dbh_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$dbh_conn->exec("set names utf8");
$dbh_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Almost all pages of my website need database. Also there is a few pages which don't need database, but because all pages pass from `index.php` then that connection executes. I mean for all pages *(even those ones which doesn't need database)* there is a database connection.

Is that a bad thing? Should I change all my structure? Again, the most of the pages need database, just a few of them doesn't. So is what I do fine?

Comment: add the db connection to a new file and include it in whichever pages require the db connection - saves lots of editing if details change or you need to adjust the connection somehow

Comment: Connecting to the DB on all pages makes it more likely you'll run into the databases's connection limit. You should only do it in pages that really use the DB.

Comment: @Barmar come on, all our sites do exactly the same. The reason of hitting the limit is NOT the connection on all pages.

Comment: @YourCommonSense So what's your opinion exactly? A connection for all pages would be fine? Or there is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [singleton](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) class for the DB connection, and not just run the code.

```
class DB {
    private static $instance;
    private $_dbh_conn = null;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (null === static::$instance) {
            static::$instance = new static();
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    protected function __construct() { 
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "dbname";
        $this->_dbh_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $this->_dbh_conn->exec("set names utf8");
        $this->_dbh_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $this->_dbh_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function &dbh_conn() {
        return $this->_dbh_conn;
    }

    private function __clone() { }
    private function __wakeup() { }
}
```

And when you include this file, you need to get the connection like this:

```
$dbh_conn = DB::getInstance()->dbh_conn();
```

Now you have the connection to the database in `$dbh_conn` and you can use it just as you did up until now. The only difference is that now you can include this file, but it won't connect to the DB unless you use the Singleton class `DB` and specifically requesting the DB connection (as I did in the above example). Additional benefit is that you're getting the same DB connection throughout the runtime of the script because you're using a design pattern of a singleton class to get the connection.